# Differential in vector calculus (Find coordinate expreession of directional derivatives)

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vector-analysis, chain-rule

$p,w\in \mathbb{R}^n$ are vectors. Hence we can write
$$w=w_1e_1+...+w_ne_n$$
with $e_i$ being the basis.

**My question is how to work out the RHS from the LHS in the following equation:**

$$\frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0}f(p+tw)=w_1\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(p)+\dots+w_n\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}(p)$$

I am also confused by the notation. What is $x_i$ in this context?

---

Here is what I tried:

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0}f(p+tw) 
&= \frac{df}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0}(p+tw)w\\
&= \frac{df}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0}(p+tw)[w_1e_1+...+w_ne_n]\\
\end{align}

I cannot really make sense of it.

EDIT: Forgot to say: $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Hint : Try it using chain rule.

Comment: @Sou燈馬想 Yes that is already what I tried. I don't understand how to apply it.

Comment: The $x_i$ are coordinates on $\mathbb{R}^n$. The $e_i$ are the bases you get for the tangent space from these coordinates.

Comment: The classical notation $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ is not very good. It must be understood as the derivative with respect to the $i$-th coordinate (in the given basis). The $x$ is unimportant here. The $i$ is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $g : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n $ defined as $g : t \mapsto p+tw$ and the function $f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, with $f: (x_1,\cdots,x_n) \mapsto f(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$. So $h = f \circ g : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Let $t_0=0$ and $g(t_0) = p + w \cdot 0 = p$. We have $g(t) =(g_1(t), \cdots , g_n(t))= (p_1 + w_1 t, \cdots , p_n+w_n t)$ and $g'(t_0) = \big(\frac{dg_1}{dt}(t_0) , \cdots , \frac{dg_n}{dt}(t_0)\big) = (w_1,\cdots,w_n)$.

The differential of function $g : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is  $g'(t)$ which is $n \times 1$ matrix, and for $f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is $f'(x) = Df(x) = \big[\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(x) \cdots \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}(x)\big]$ is a $1\times n$ matrix so the differential of the composition $h = f \circ g$ is just a number $h'(t) = Df(g(t)) \cdot g'(t)$.

By [**chain rule**](http://www.springer.com/br/book/9783540874515),
\begin{align}
h'(t_0) &=\frac{d}{dt}\Bigg|_{t_0=0} f(p+wt) =(f \circ g)'(t_0) = Df(g(t_0)) \cdot g'(t_0) \\
&= \Big[ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(p) \cdots \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}(p) \Big] 
    \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{dg_1}{dt}(t_0)\\
    \frac{dg_2}{dt}(t_0)\\
    \frac{dg_3}{dt} (t_0)\\
    \end{bmatrix} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} w_i \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(p)
\end{align}

Comment: OK, everything makes sense now. Although I think you make a mistake $g(t_0)=p$ right? Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Opps. I'll fix that.